# NextJS 13 next-auth authentication with Strapi CMS

Tags: typescript, strapi, next-auth, next.js13

I am trying to implement Next-Auth on latest NextJS 13 with a strapi backend. However, most of the documentations that are available are either stale or do not capture the use of Google as a provider. I have fumbled around but nothing seems to bear fruits. Here is my implementation so far. My code is using TypeScript:

I created a route.ts file in: `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]` with the following content:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ user, session, token }) {
            session.user = token as any;
            session.user.id = user ? user.id : null;
            return Promise.resolve(session);
        },
        
        async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
            const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
            if (isSignIn && account) {
                const response = await fetch(
                    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/auth/${account.provider}/callback?access_token=${account?.accessToken}`
                );
                const data = await response.json();
                token.jwt = data.jwt;
                token.id = data.user.id;
            }
            return Promise.resolve(token);
        },
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

So, the login and logout works fine with the code, but the problem comes when I try to link this to `Strapi`. The thing is, I don't really know what is to be done. Some docs talk of first calling the database and saving the data before fetching the access token from strapi, for example: [User Authentication in Next.js with Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/user-authentication-in-next-js-with-strapi). However, the documentation appears to be stale as Next-Auth recommends using adapters for database. But there is no place where this is described for Strapi as most docs on using adapters suggest creating of new models.

So, my main problem is, how do I persist this logged in user to Strapi database after successful login?

How do I get the access token from Strapi for subsequent API calls that need authentication?

A pointer to a working code/docs/example will help alot.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got a workaround this. First of all, I had to put the fetch request in the jwt callback in a try catch block so that I could get what error was affecting it. Also, after a long debugging, I realized that the `accessToken` from the Google Account object is actually written as `access_token` and not `accessToken` as most documentation put it. Here is the working code after making the changes:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
        })
    ],

    session: { strategy: "jwt" },

    callbacks: {
        async session({ user, session, token }) {
            session.user = token as any;
            session.user.id = user ? user.id : null;
            return Promise.resolve(session);
        },
        
        async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
            const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
            if (isSignIn && account) {
                try {
                    console.log("Google Account >>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", account);
                    const public_url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;
                    const response = await fetch(
                        `${public_url}/api/auth/${account.provider}/callback?access_token=${account?.access_token}`
                    );
                    const data = await response.json();
                    console.log("Strapi Callback Data >>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", data);
                    token.jwt = data.jwt;
                    token.id = data.user.id;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Fetch failed:', error);
                }
            }
            return Promise.resolve(token);
        },
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I hope it helps others who are having the same problem as I had.

On a side note, I had to use `127.0.0.1:1337` instead of `localhost:1337` as the latter gave me connection error.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same setup (FE: NextJS.13 and BE: Strapi) I'm going through the same process. I realized that a potentially less convoluted approach would be to just implement the Authentication (Login/Signup) only using Strapi avoiding to use NextAuth, like this guy is doing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_x-5awVL5U&pp=ygUjc2V0dXAgTmV4dEF1dGggd2l0aCBTdHJhcGkgcHJvdmlkZXI%3D
He setup auth with providers and shows you step by step. I another of his videos he uses users/me as an endpoint to display a specific user. This endpoint is STRAPI support and automatically authenticates via JWT. Very very useful and smooth.

(I found NextAuth documentation quite messy, probably because they are migrating it to Auth.js)

Anyway thank's for sharing your code. I look forward to your next comment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34683594)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also implement authorization with strapi and next. I had a fetch error. The only thing that helped me was this combination of environment variables:
NEXTAUTH_URL=http:localhost:3000
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:1337